# how to GET THE selected value from the list view to be displayed on the second activity?

Tags: android, arrays, android-intent, android-listview

i am a creating a simple android app that will make the user choose one item  and this selected item will be displayed in the second activity using intent  but the problem is that i do not know how to make the selected value be displayed  i just know how to make a specific value to be displayed .. can anyone help me ????

## MainActivity.java

```
package com.devleb.listviewdemo;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
    TextView txt;
    private static final String[] items = { "doctor", "engineer", "lawer",
            "developer", "employee", "business man", "auditer", "cashier" };



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items));
        txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

        // txt.setText(items[position]);

        Intent i = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("testonArray", items);
        startActivity(i);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

## SecondActivity.java

```
package com.devleb.listviewdemo;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SecondActivity extends Activity {

    TextView txt;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

        Bundle extras=getIntent().getExtras();
        String [] values = extras.getStringArray ("testonArray");
        txt = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.txt2);
        if (values != null && values.length > 0 && txt != null){
           txt.setText(values [0]);
        }

        }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.second, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code in First Activity:

```
   +@Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

        // txt.setText(items[position]);

        // Try to send the items[position] in the intent
        Intent i = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("testonArray", items[position].toString());
        startActivity(i);
    }
```

Code in Second Activity:

```
   Bundle extras=getIntent().getExtras();
   String selected_item=extras.getString("testonArray");
   txt = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.txt2);
   txt.setText(selected_item);
```

Comment: ok and in the second activity  what i should write in the code to display the values selected ??

Answer (score 1):

To add to Virag's point, getting the data from Activity 2 (in onCreate works):

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String value = intent.getStringExtra("testonArray"); //value to get
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to display your text value, you can use Toast...

```
Toast.makeText(this, "Here is my toast !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Alternatively, you can use a dialog :

```
            AlertDialog.Builder adb = new Builder(this);
            adb.setMessage("My main message");
            adb.setNeutralButton("OK", null);
            adb.show();
```

You may want to use `getApplicationContext()` instead of `this`

Comment: yes i know but what i need is that to display the selected value form the listview from the first Activity to be displayed in the text view in the second Activity

Answer (score 0):

```
i.putExtra("testonArray", items[position]);
```

in Second Activity

```
String value=extras.getString("testonArray");
```

Answer (score -1):

MainActivity onClick

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
{
@Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
String  itemValue = (String) list.getItemAtPosition(position);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, itemValue);
        startActivity(intent);
    } 
});
}
```

SecondActivity

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

    TextView textView = new TextView (this);
    textView.setText(message);

    setContentView(textView);}
```